# Python Class method definition : "unexpected indent"

Tags: python, django

I am getting started with Django and Python so naturally I'm doing the polls project tutorial. I am working under Windows 7 with Python 2.7.9 and Django 1.3.7

I have this piece of code (with line numbers under brackets):

```
(3) class Poll(models.Model):
(4)     question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
(5)     pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
(6)     def __unicode__(self):
(7)         return self.question
```

and when trying to run "manage.py shell" I get the following error :

> File "C:\Users...\mysite\polls\models.py", line 6
>
> > def **unicode**(self)
> >
> > ^
>
> IndentationError: unexpected indent

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check indentation. Also take care of tabs/spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `class` header is in same indentation with its content , you need to refine the indentation (**as a pythonic way use 4 space for indentation** ):

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```

Comment: My indentation on the post wasn't matching the one in my code. BUT Thank you for the 4 spaces tip, I didn't know that. I am used to hit "tab" for quick indent. So thank you ^^.

Comment: @KiJéy welcome , the error is because of you mixed the tabs with spaces you need to use same white space for all the lines , an as i say its better to use 4 space ! ;)

Comment: yes because part of my code was manually typed (with tab) and the rest (the def part) was copy-pasted from the tutorial page. On my IDE 4 spaces look like a tab.

Answer (score 1):

Python works on proper indendation. Your code should be

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)//see these as part of class variable
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self): //part of class's operation
        return self.question
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't indent the post correctly but my code IS. I've just updated my post