# Python Indentation Error when there is no indent error

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, indentation

Is it me or the interpreter? I see no indentation error in my code but it kept telling me that there is an error! I use auto indentation so it should be ok. When ever there is an indentation error, I backspace then indent again and it seems to fix it because the indentation error is not on that line anymore but on the other line. Can someone please tell me what is wrong

```
class LogicGate:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.label = n
        self.output = None

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.label

    def getOutput(self):
        self.output = self.performGateLogic()
        return self.output
```

Self answer: the auto indentation of my IDE is indent with tab, and sometimes when I back space I indent it with spaces again. So the problem is mixing spaces and tabs. I recommend setting your IDE to indent with spaces or don't use tabs. See  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/

Comment: Provide the full traceback. Is it an indentation error due to inconsistent usage of tabs and spaces?

Comment: Why is this upvoted?

Comment: Looking at the raw source of your post, your `def __init__` and `self.label = n` lines use tabs and everything else uses spaces. You should only use one or the other (preferably spaces)

Comment: @BhargavRao A basic Python tutorial would show where the indentation is wrong. A quick google search could have helped OP (or just look at [some relevant posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460631/python-class-method-definition-unexpected-indent)).

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Fair enough! I just said that do not post comments like that! If you feel you need to vote, vote! :) I hope you got my point. Ty

Comment: That's why i made my post as CW..

Comment: @AvinashRaj A well calculated move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tabs and spaces must be getting mixed up. Set you editor to 4 spaces for a tab. You can also turn on whitespace indicator on the editor, which can help resolving the indentation errors.

Answer (score 3):

It would be,

```
class LogicGate:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.label = n
        self.output = None

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.label

    def getOutput(self):
        self.output = self.performGateLogic()
        return self.output
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class should look like this:

```
class LogicGate:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.label = n
        self.output = None

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.label

    def getOutput(self):
        self.output = self.performGateLogic()
        return self.output
```